# ELF file format find shared object for symbol

Tags: elf, dynamic-linking

(in Windows) PE file format contains Import table with `Module\Dll Name` which tells PE loader where to search for symbol e.g. `KERNEL32.dll -> CreateFileW`

In the ELF file format there is `Symbol table` with `info` field which tells if the symbol is `Global\Local\Weak\etc.`

My question is how does the Unix loader know what is the module, shared object where to search for this symbol e.g. `???? -> snprintf`

I noticed objdump can dump this info `objdump -T /bin/ls`.
[image]
 `GLIBC_2.2.5 snprintf`

Could someone with more knowledge on ELF file format shed some light on Unix dynamic-linking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does the Unix loader know what is the module,
>   shared object where to search for this symbol

Short answer: it does not. It just searches the whole list of loaded modules until the symbol is found (or not). A small degree of control over more exact symbol matching can be achieved via versioned symbols but otherwise it's pretty much a free-for-all.

By design, the ELF symbol space is **global** (or flat) so any symbol can be *preempted* by another module. This is used for example when [hooking symbols via LD_PRELOAD_LIBRARY environment variable](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/low-level/kernel/2016/08/29/16-48-53-the_-ld_preload-_trick/).